# Как поэтапно открывать ссылки - PHP

Tags: php

Имеется следующий код:

```
...
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

вывожу результат:

```
echo $data;
```

открывается внешний сайт внутри тестового домена, ссылок таких 200 поэтапно необходимо каждого из них открыть в интервале 5 секунд (каждые 5 секунд открыть страницу из списка). Суть каким образом это прописать чтобы внутри тестовго домена эти страницы открывались после каждые 5 сек новая страница.

P.S сейчас получается так (крайне неудобно и нагружает вкладку браузера)

```
echo $data;
sleep(5);
```

при этом другие ссылки отркываются поверх открытой ссылки (на одной вкладке 10-ток сайтов друг за другом)

Answer (score 0):

Php: Выведи на странице все 200 ссылок в формате `<a href>`.

Подключи Jquery,
Js: Собери все a тэги, сделай foreach, возьми href  из каждого элемента и открывай их значения в новом окне при помощи window.open([url_of_link], '_blank'), и сразу после добавляй свой sleep